# How to resolve Missing Workload components in Visual Studio for .NET MAUI?

Tags: visual-studio, maui

I've been trying to get into .NET MAUI development but I've been having an uphill battle getting the workloads installed and working.

I've received several different errors, which I've resolved up to the point I'm at now. I don't know where to go from here with what I have for an error below. Scouring the Internet is drying up on leads.

The error I have at the moment happens anytime I try to open a project or reload the project (after it fails the first time).

> The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.SDK.WorkloadAutoImportPropsLocator' specified could not be found. C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.ImportWorkloads.props

I have done the following to try and resolve this (and also to resolve other errors I was receiving originally).

- Reinstalled the MAUI Workload using VS Installer
- Reinstalled VS entirely
- Reboots interspersed throughout the reinstall process for both the Workload and VS itself
- Reinstalled VS entirely and scanned Registry for straggler installs of .NET SDK components
- Set System Variable MSBuildSDKsPath to C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.302\Sdks
- Set System Variable MSBuildEnableWorkloadResolver to true
- Tried installing the MAUI Workload on a completely different system running Windows 10 (the first system was Win11) and experienced similar if not the same issues.

While some of the above pieces solved other issues I was having (specifically the MSBuildSDKsPath solved the most issues thus far), I don't know where to go from here.

Some resources I've already tried, if it helps

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/troubleshooting
- [.Net MAUI app not building due to missing workload but the workload is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76135965/net-maui-app-not-building-due-to-missing-workload-but-the-workload-is-installed)
- https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/17461
- https://github.com/dotnet/installer/issues/10551
- [MSBUILD throws error: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46257393/msbuild-throws-error-the-sdk-microsoft-net-sdk-specified-could-not-be-found)

Comment: Have you tried restoring your VS?

Comment: I would need some clarification here. Restoring of any kind seems unlikely to help if I've reinstalled the software with a number of different levels of cleanup scrutiny.

Comment: I do not see the benefit of performing a repair when, again, I've reinstalled the software multiple times, on different systems, all still presenting the same problem once the reinstallation is complete.

Comment: You can report this problem in the Visual studio directly. Please see this document about [Report a problem with the Visual Studio product or installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022).

Comment: I have reported the problem through VS directly. It's essentially a verbatim copy of what is here. If I get an answer I'll put it here.